# unity общение сервер-клиент

Tags: c#, unity3d, сеть, клиент-сервер

Необходимо чтобы Клиент передавал данные(переменные) Серверу, а Сервер отвечал на запрос

Рабочий способ нашел только с помощью

```
[RPC]  
void Func(){ }

networkView.RPC ("Func", RPCMode.All, "data");
```

Но это не совсем то, что нужно, да и написано, что способ устарел

Пробовал

```
[ClientCallback]
[Command]
[ServerCallback]
[ClientRpc]
[Client]
[Server]
```

Но, к сожалению, ни разу не получилось передать данные от сервера к клиенту или наоборот.
Пробовал

```
NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnect);
NetworkServer.SendToAll(MSG_SCORE, msg);
```

Но не разобрался как правильно передавать данные и как оно работает

Например у клиента int i = 0;
Как изменить с сервера переменную у клиента на 1, используя стандартные методы unity?

Comment: смотрите в сторону `socket`

Comment: На сервере иоже Юнити?

Comment: Да, хотелось бы, чтобы сервер тоже был юнити

Comment: @badan `[RPC]` устарели с выходом Unity3d 5.1. Про новую сеть тут читать https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/s/multiplayer-networking